# How can I await C# tasks in order, and not in parallel?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a set of asynchronous tests, which run on external hardware.

I can run them in order but because all of these tests have side effects, I'd like to be able to shuffle them and run them over and over.

When I put them in a list and try to await each afterwards, they all run in parallel instead of being run 1 by 1.

I'd like to be able to shuffle the list and then run them all in order.

**How can I run the tests (`List<Task<bool>`) in order while keeping them in a list so that I can shuffle the list?**

```
private async void RunVisca()
{
    Ptz ptz = new Ptz(SelectedComPort, (byte)(1), SelectedBaudRate, Node.DeviceType.PTZ);

    UpdateResults("VISCA TEST START\n\n");

    // Method 1: Correct - Runs in order
    await VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, true);
    await VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, false);
    await VTestLimitsCl(ptz, 125, 20);
    await VTestLimitsOl(ptz, 125, 20);

    // Method 2: Incorrect - Runs in parallel
    List<Task<bool>> tests = new List<Task<bool>>();
    tests.Add(VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, true));
    tests.Add(VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, false));
    tests.Add(VTestLimitsCl(ptz, 125, 20));
    tests.Add(VTestLimitsOl(ptz, 125, 20));

    // Tasks all run in parallel here - should they not run in order?
    foreach(Task<bool> test in tests)
    {
        _ = await test.ConfigureAwait(true);
    }

    UpdateResults("\nTEST COMPLETE\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You just wait them in order, but they are executed unordered.

Comment: Any time you wrote `async void`: it is probably a very serious mistake. IMO this should be `private async Task RunVisca()` (or `RunViscaAsync()`) so that the caller can know when it has finished.

Comment: "Because all of these tests have side effects, I'd like to be able to shuffle them and run them over and over." - Why? "Because it is raining, I need an umbrella" makes sense to me. Your sentence doesn't.

Comment: "I'd like to be able to shuffle the list and then run them all in order." - and this? What?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: This is a command launched by a button click in the UI. I think it more or less has to be void

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?redirectedfrom=MSDN#task-status) means that calling an `async` method, which returns a `Task`, will return a *hot task*.

A `Task` in a hot state has already been started. This can be proven by checking the `Task.Status` property, which will never be [`TaskStatus.Created`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskStatus_Created).

A *cold task* will have a `Task.Status` property of `TaskStatus.Created` & will only start running when [`Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start?view=net-5.0) is called on the instance.

The only way to create a cold task is to use `Task`/`Task<T>`'s respective public constructors.

---

Since your tasks are returned by an async method, they will already be running when they are returned to you.

To run them in order & not in parallel, you mustn't create them after one another unless the previous task has been completed. To ensure this, you will have to `await` them separately.

**This results in method 1 being the correct way to run *hot tasks* in order & not in parallel.**

```
await VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, true);
await VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, false);
await VTestLimitsCl(ptz, 125, 20);
await VTestLimitsOl(ptz, 125, 20);
```

---

Method 2/3 is incorrect as it will run your tasks in parallel.

You are adding hot tasks returned from your `async` methods to your list, without awaiting them. They will have *already started running* before you have moved on to add the next task to the list.

The 1st task is **not awaited** so the 2nd task will start immediately after, regardless of if task 1 finished or not.

The 2nd task is not awaited so the 3rd task etc.

With method 2/3, they will always run in parallel.

```
tests.Add(VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, true));
tests.Add(VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, false));
```

---

The real question is how to run *cold tasks* in order so that we can store them in a list yet take advantage of deferred execution until we loop over our list.

**The solution is to store delegates instead**, which will trigger the below Task constructor:

`public Task (Func<TResult> function);`

This will create cold tasks, letting you run the `Task` when the `Func<Task<bool>>` is invoked:

```
var tests = new List<Func<Task<bool>>>();
tests.Add(() => VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, true));
tests.Add(() => VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, false));
tests.Add(() => VTestLimitsCl(ptz, 125, 20));
tests.Add(() => VTestLimitsOl(ptz, 125, 20));
    
foreach (var test in tests) {
     await test();
}
```

---

This demo program below will clearly show tasks running in order vs. parallel.

```
class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // 1... 2... 3... 4...
        var tasksThatRunInOrder = new List<Func<Task<bool>>>();
        tasksThatRunInOrder.Add(() => Test("1"));
        tasksThatRunInOrder.Add(() => Test("2"));
        tasksThatRunInOrder.Add(() => Test("3"));
        tasksThatRunInOrder.Add(() => Test("4"));

        foreach (var test in tasksThatRunInOrder)
            await test();

        // 1, 2, 3, 4
        var testsThatRunInParallel = new List<Task<bool>>();
        testsThatRunInParallel.Add(Test("1"));
        testsThatRunInParallel.Add(Test("2"));
        testsThatRunInParallel.Add(Test("3"));
        testsThatRunInParallel.Add(Test("4"));

        foreach (var test in testsThatRunInParallel)
            await test;
    }

    private static async Task<bool> Test(string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tasks start when they are created. Since you're creating all of them at the same time without awaiting any of them, they're going to execute in a undetermined parallel manner. I think maybe you wanted to store delegates instead. These aren't executed until invoked.

```
var tests = new List<Func<Task<bool>>>();
tests.Add( () => VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, true) );
tests.Add( () => VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, false) );
tests.Add( () => VTestLimitsCl(ptz, 125, 20) );
tests.Add( () => VTestLimitsOl(ptz, 125, 20) );
    
foreach(var test in tests)
{
    _ = await test(); 
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a list where you randomize the order you want to run things and then call the functions that create the tasks accordingly. For example:

```
    static async Task RunTasks()
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        var order = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
        var shuffledOrder = order.OrderBy(a => rng.Next()).ToList();

        foreach (var i in shuffledOrder)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
            case 1:
                await LoadFile1();
                break;
            case 2:
                await LoadFile2();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try awaiting without assignment to a throwaway variable.

Answer (score -3):

How about call chain of `ContinueWith`?

```
Task.Run(async () => 
{
    await VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, true);
}).ContinueWith(async (_) => 
{ 
    await VTestDriveClosedLoop(ptz, false);
}).ContinueWith(async (_) => 
{ 
    await VTestLimitsCl(ptz, 125, 20);
}).ContinueWith(async (_) => 
{ 
    await VTestLimitsOl(ptz, 125, 20);
});
```

Comment: This is a very bad solution as they could just await them separately and gain the same results - no need for so much extra syntactical sugar and Task wrapping

Comment: The `ContinueWith` method is [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), and it doesn't work well with async/await. If you watch carefully you'll see that the `ContinueWith(async` in your example returns nested `Task<Task>`s, not simple `Task`s. And then by chaining multiple `ContinueWith(async` in this way you attach continuation to the outer task that just invokes the `VTestDriveClosedLoop` etc, not to the inner task that respresents the completion of these asynchronous methods. In other words, your code does't do what you expect it to do.