# Problem with running tasks sequentially using ContinueWith

Tags: wpf, async-await, continuewith

I want to start a proccess by checking toggleButton and after finishing proccess toggleButton be Unchecked.

Here is my code.

Proccess.xaml :

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding StartProccessCommand}" Content="Proccessing"  IsChecked="{Binding isChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"></ToggleButton>
```

ProccessViewModel.cs :

```
public class ProccessViewModel: BindableBase 
{
  private bool _isChecked = false;
  public bool isChecked
  {
     get { return _isChecked; }
     set { SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value); }
  }

  public DelegateCommand StartProccessCommand{ get; set; }
  
  public ProccessViewModel()
   {
      StartProccessCommand= new DelegateCommand(OnToggleButtonClicked);
   }

  public async void OnToggleButtonClicked()
    {
       await Task.Run(() => {

          isChecked= true;
      
          for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
            {
              Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

       }).ContinueWith((x) =>
           {
              for (int i = 50000; i < 100000; i++)
               {
                 Console.WriteLine(i);
               }

              isChecked= false;
           }
}
```

BUT when I run code ToggleButton Unchecked immediately after checking.

Result :

> ToggleButton Checked
>
> ToggleButton Unchecked
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 49999
>
> 50000
>
> 50001
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 100000

Comment: Was hated for that sequential calls here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442685/awaiting-tasks-in-order-and-not-in-parallel/69442887#69442887. As explained, `ContinueWith` didn't do what you expect it should do. From comment out of there, you can check that discussion: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html. And the solution is to run tasks and await them **separately**, one by one, and set `isChecked` false only after all `await`ings.

Comment: Where do `ToggleButton Checked` and `ToggleButton Unchecked` come from in the output?

Comment: @Haukinger - When isChecked= true; and then isChecked= flase;  runs.

Comment: Why is `IsChecked` bound in `TwoWay` mode? It should follow the `isChecked` property, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `ContinueWith` with `await`? It makes no sense since the remainder of `OnToggleButtonClicked` will be executed once the awaited `Task` has finished.

Set the property, await the first `Task` and then await another `Task` and set the property back to `false`:

```
public async void OnToggleButtonClicked()
{
    isChecked = true;
    await Task.Run(() => {

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    });

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 50000; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    });
    isChecked = false;
}
```